# binding combobox with data and save as foreign key c#

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I am writing an application for the applicants of universities using c#. On the first form I have several textboxes ,radiobutton and a combo box.   All these are related to a database (student) that i create. There is a `table tbl_nationality` and a table `tblstudent` in the database. In the table `tbl_nationality` we have the column `Nationality_id` and `Country`. The `nationality_id` is a foreign key in the table `tblstudent` .

I wrote some lines of code to populate the data from the column country in the combo box (cmbnationality) . The problem is, now I need to save the data from the forms and the combo box nationality is a foreign key in the table tblstudent. How do I do to save the foreign key `nationality_id` in tblstudent when I am displaying the country from `tbl_nationality`.

```
void FillNationality()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog = student; Data Source = Yudish-PC";
    string Query = "select * from tbl_nationality ;";
    SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
    SqlDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
          string nationality = myReader.GetString (1);
            cmbnationality.Items.Add(nationality);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);            
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you populate the combobox, use the Id as the value and the country as the display text. When you update the database, grab the SelectedValue property of the combobox, which will be the Id. If the Id isn't something you want exposed, you can hold the data in the Session object and use the Country as a lookup on that table (just loop it). Should be pretty straight-forward.

Setting the table in session:

`Session["myTable"] = ds.tables["myTable"];`

Getting the value from the combobox:

`myCombo.SelectedValue`

You should also look into binding a datasource (your table from the dataset retrieved from the db) to your combobox.